# Why are components that are saved in parent state not updating?

Tags: reactjs

I'm building a basic timer app and I'm a newbie. Multiple timers (UnitTimercomponent instance) can be set, their time adjusted and run sequentially. I saved them in the parent's state so that they'll keep the time the user has set if the app is re-rendered.

I am passing them an isActive boolean as a prop, so that the timer knows if he has to run or not. The isActive boolean is made up of an if statement that by default is false and will equivalate to true once the app started (activeTimerId will be set to 1).

The problem is, that when the app is started and I set activeTimerId to 1, the UnitTimer's props don't update. The isActive boolean still remains false, although the underlying values changed and {timerId === this.state.activeTimerId} should equivalate to true

```
import React from 'react';
import UnitTimer from './components/unittimer';

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            timer: [],
            numTimers: 1,
            activeTimerId: 0
        };
    }


    addNewTimer = () => {
        this.setState(prevState => {
            let key = this.state.timer.length + 1;
            let timerId = this.state.timer.length + 1;
            return this.state.timer.push(
                <UnitTimer
                    key={key}
                    Id={timerId}
                    isActive={timerId === this.state.activeTimerId}
                />
            );
        });
    };


    startTimer = () => {
        this.setState({
            activeTimerId: 1,
        });
    };
```

```
class UnitTimer extends Component {
    componentWillReceiveProps (nextProps) {
        if (nextProps.isActive && !this.props.isActive && !nextProps.timerIsPaused && !this.state.timerOn) {
            this.startTimer();
        } else if (this.props.isActive && nextProps.timerIsPaused) {
            this.stopTimer();
        } else if (this.props.isActive && !nextProps.timerIsPaused && nextProps.isActive && !this.state.timerOn) {
            this.startTimer();
        } else if (!nextProps.isActive) {
            this.resetTimer();
        } else if (nextProps.appHasBeenReset || this.props.appHasBeenReset) {
            this.resetTimer();
        }
    }

  state = {
      timerOn: false,
      timerStart: 0,
      timerTime: 300000,
      timerTitle: ''
  };

render () {
      const { timerTime } = this.state;

      let cssClass = (this.props.isActive) ? "unitTimerActive" : "unitTimer";
      return (
          <div className={cssClass} >
              <Input
                  className={(this.props.isActive ? "inputActive" : "inputOnDark")}
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Timer Title"
                  name="timerTitle"
                  value={this.state.timerTitle}
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
              />

              <div className={(this.props.isActive ? "timeActive" : "time")}>
                  {minutes} : {seconds}
              </div>

          </div>
      );
  }
```

Before this version the app was running successfully when I was not saving the UnitTimer in the apps state, but then I had the problem of loosing the settings of the timers at each re-render. There's probably a better way to circumvent that problem, I'd also be glad about any suggestion as to how I could better structure this, I'm sure what I'm doing is not best practice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you provide complete code ?

Comment: You should include your render method in your question too. Your `addNewTimer` method is a bit strange. You are doing a lot of logic inside `setState` which is unnecessary. `setState` needs a new object returned, but you aren't doing that.

Comment: You can't mutate state directly, like you do with `this.state.timer.push`. Direct mutations won't trigger re-renders, and can cause buggy behaviour. Do whatever you need for the new state first, then call `setState` with the data. Also doing the logic inside `setState` is kinda weird, you don't really need to do that since you already have access to `prevState` via `this.state`. So just build the new timer array and call `setState` with it.

Comment: I'm a total beginner, I'm sure a lot of my code is weird :) About building a new array; the problem is that the time of each timer is set by the user and is stored in the timer component state and will get lost if I create a new array rather than adding more timers to the existing array. So I'm assuming if I use the array from prevState, add a new timer to it and then call setState with the altered array from prevState, each timer component will still have it's original state with the time the user has set. Is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this line `this.state.timer.push` you are mutating state. State should be immutable.

Also, I wouldn't store `UnitTimer` component in `state`. Instead, you can store just an array of `id`s, and then you can use `Array.prototype.map()` function in `render()`.

Try this:

```
  addNewTimer = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      timer: [...prevState.timer,
      <UnitTimer
        key={prevState.timer.length + 1}
        Id={prevState.timer.length + 1}
        isActive={timerId === this.state.activeTimerId}
      />]
    }))
  };
```